# Connect active mq to my standalone JVM

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have downloaded Apache active mq and I am able to run it via `activemq.xml` config file. How can I monitor my JVMs ESB data via this xml file.

I need to expose these attributes: `Name, Enqueue Count, Dequeue Count, Consumer count etc`
The XML file is as under:

```
<!--
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="BROKER1"    useJmx="true" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <!--
                    Limit ALL queues and topics to using 5mb of memory and turn on producer flow control
                -->
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="5mb"/>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="5mb">
                    <dispatchPolicy>
                        <!--
                          Use total ordering, see:
                             http://activemq.apache.org/total-ordering.html
                        -->
                        <strictOrderDispatchPolicy/>
                    </dispatchPolicy>
                    <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                        <!--
                            Upon subscription, receive the last image sent
                            on the destination.
                        -->
                        <lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy/>
                    </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <!--
        The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
        JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
        the JVM. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
        Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
        mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>


      <!--
        The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
        use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
      -->
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?  maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
         <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>

<!--
    Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
    The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml      file

    Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article looks like it should be helpful for you.  I imagine that you would want to use jconsole (run from command line) to connect to ActiveMQ via JMX, which gives you access to the data you need.

http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

Comment: I have gone through this document, but I am not getting any idea how can I connect my ESB to the active MQ.

Comment: @Mark's suggestion is a good one if you're looking for interactive monitoring (i.e. eyeballs on screens).  Configure the broker to expose a JMX endpoint, use JConsole to attach to the process, and drill into the MBeans tab to find whatever info you're looking for.  If you're looking for stand-alone monitoring, you can still use JMX, but you'll need to write code using the Java API (or another API) to pull out the things you care about.